# ¿Como puedo obtener todos los registros relacionados de manera jerarquica en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, recursión, sql-server-2014

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server 2014 con dos campos , cada una es el id de un empleado, cada registro representa la relación de ambos empleados, quedando algo así

[image: captura de la tabla de relaciones de empleados]

La idea es que si se hace un query filtrando por el ID="3020" se pueda obtener la lista de todos los trabajadores que tengan relación con ese id

De tal manera que la consulta nos regrese esto.
Para el ejemplo del Id="3020" debería regresar:

3010
3005
3006
3004
1001

Si seleccionamos el Id="1050"

4000

He tratado con la cláusula With y recursividad pero obtengo problemas que indican que se excedió el máximo de recursividad.

De antemano muchas gracias , espero puedan orientarme un poco

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, sentencias DDL-DML para poder reproducir y testear el caso que propones. Por aportarlo yo, me he tomado la libertad de elegir algunos nombres y configuraciones:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EmployeesRelations
(
    EmployeeRelationId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Employee1 INT,
    Employee2 INT
);

INSERT INTO EmployeesRelations (Employee1, Employee2)
VALUES (3020, 3010),
       (3010, 3005),
       (3010, 3006),
       (3005, 3004),
       (3006, 1001),
       (4000, 1050);
```

Y en segundo lugar, la consulta recursiva de acuerdo con tus requisitos, para encontrar los empleados que guarden una relación de cualquier grado con el empleado de número especificado en la condición, utilizando una **Expresión de Tabla Común o CTE** por sus siglas en inglés:

```sql
WITH EmployeeHierarchy AS (
    SELECT Employee1 AS EmployeeID, Employee2 AS RelatedEmployeeID
    FROM EmployeesRelations
    WHERE Employee1 = 3020  -- Especificar el número o ID del empleado a consultar

    UNION ALL

    SELECT eh.EmployeeID, er.Employee2 AS RelatedEmployeeID
    FROM EmployeeHierarchy eh
    INNER JOIN EmployeesRelations er ON eh.RelatedEmployeeID = er.Employee1
)
SELECT RelatedEmployeeID
FROM EmployeeHierarchy;
```

La CTE `EmployeeHierarchy` se usa para almacenar los resultados intermedios a medida que se realiza la búsqueda recursiva en la tabla. Si te fijas, en la primera parte de la CTE se seleccionan los registros de `EmployeesRelations` donde `Employee1` es igual al ID o número del empleado buscado (en el ejemplo, 3020). Así se obtiene la primera capa de empleados relacionados directamente o en primer grado con el empleado consultado.

En la segunda parte de la CTE es donde se realiza propiamente la recursión. Se seleccionan los registros de la CTE anterior (`EmployeeHierarchy`) y se unen con la tabla `EmployeesRelations` utilizando la condición de igualdad `eh.RelatedEmployeeID = er.Employee1`. Esto selecciona los empleados relacionados con los empleados encontrados en la capa anterior.

La recursión continúa hasta que no se encuentren más registros relacionados en la tabla `EmployeesRelations`. Cada iteración de la recursión agrega una nueva capa de empleados relacionados a la CTE.

Al final, la consulta principal selecciona el campo `RelatedEmployeeID` de la CTE `EmployeeHierarchy`, devolviendo la lista de empleados relacionados con el empleado deseado.

Sería muy sencillo adaptar este código para incorporarlo a una función o procedimiento almacenado parametrizado que pudiera ser invocado pasándole por argumento el empleado cuyas relaciones se desea buscar.

Aunque no estaba especificado en tu propuesta, he decidido devolver los empleados relacionados como registros y no propiamente como una "lista" por ser la manera más natural de trabajo en consultas a bases de datos relacionales.